# Why is there a "±" in lea rax, [ rip ± 0xeb3]?

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, x86-64, disassembly

I just started learning about assembly language in Kali Linux in VMware. I have a Ryzen 5 CPU. In the below code snippet, I have a few things I don't understand.

- What is the meaning of `lea rax, [rip ± 0xeb3]` at <main + 17>? I understand what `lea` does, but what is the meaning of ±?
- And what is the purpose of RDI after getting updated?

```
(gdb) list
1       #include<stdio.h>
2
3       int main(){
4               int i;
5               for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
6                       printf("Hello World!\n");
7               }
8               return 0;
9       }
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000001139 <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x000000000000113a <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x000000000000113d <+4>:     sub    rsp,0x10
   0x0000000000001141 <+8>:     mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x0
   0x0000000000001148 <+15>:    jmp    0x115d <main+36>
   0x000000000000114a <+17>:    lea    rax,[rip±0xeb3]        # 0x2004
   0x0000000000001151 <+24>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x0000000000001154 <+27>:    call   0x1030 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000001159 <+32>:    add    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1
   0x000000000000115d <+36>:    cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x9
   0x0000000000001161 <+40>:    jle    0x114a <main+17>
   0x0000000000001163 <+42>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000000000001168 <+47>:    leave  
   0x0000000000001169 <+48>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```

Edit:

```
gdb -v        
GNU gdb (Debian 12.1-3) 12.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: Could be useful to show the output of `gdb -v`

Comment: I would suspect that it is actually supposed to be "-" but that it is being printed as "+ -" and then getting transformed to ± for some reason.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir `0x1151 + 0xeb3 = 0x2004` though

Comment: What shell and terminal are you using? Give us more details about your environment. AFAICT that symbol simply is not to be found anywhere in GDB/libopcodes code.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I was using a normal terminal in Kali Linux, not as the root user, but the user was privileged. Can you please mention what details do you need about the environment?

Comment: I can reproduce this. It's not a plus-minus, it's an underlined plus. Possibly due to a wrong color escape sequence.

Comment: Ok, found the bug. gdb 12.1 [uses Python (!!!) to colorize its output](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Output-Styling.html). Specifically, it uses the Pygments packages. Which handles x64 code badly, [here's a test case](https://pastebin.com/dgvSRYH4). The (yet to be released) next version uses and entirely different coloring code, where each disassembler function can introduce style markers in its output and the `disassemble` command (`gdb/disassemble.c`) translate those markers into terminal escapes.

Comment: OK so it means + right? Thanks for checking out.

Comment: @KaranTejas you can do `set style disassembler enabled off` to disable the disassembler styling, this should fix the formatting issues.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: You could post that as an answer.  BTW, on my Arch Linux system, in Konsole, your pastebin test-case prints an underlined `+` which looks confusing at first, but once you know to look for it, is clearly a `+` with an underline of the whole cell.  And it copy/pastes as `+`, not `±`

Comment: @PeterCordes That's how I found it was a plus and not a plus-minus: by copy-pasting it to remove any formatting. Then spent an hour trying to figure out what is wrong with the coloring code only to realize (later) that I was looking at GDB 13 :)  I'll post an answer so this can be marked as answered.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: I assume the OP had copy/pasted from their terminal into the question, where the code blocks have `±`.  Pretty misleading [mcve] if actual GDB isn't outputting that character on their terminal, without saying anything about manually editing to make it look like what they see.  Maybe some terminal emulator copy/pastes an underlined `+` as `±`, or some other innocent explanation.  Hope that didn't cost you too much extra time when tracking this down.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a [plus-minus (±, Unicode point 0x00b1)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00B1), it's an underlined plus.
If you copy-paste it, you get only a plus (+).

[GDB 12.1 uses Python to colorize each line of its disassembler output](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Output-Styling.html).    Specifically, it uses the Pygments packages, which, at the current version 2.11.2, handle x64 code badly, here's a test case:

```
from pygments import formatters, lexers, highlight
 
def colorize_disasm(content, gdbarch):
    # Don't want any errors.
    try:
        lexer = lexers.get_lexer_by_name("asm")
        formatter = formatters.TerminalFormatter()
        return highlight(content, lexer, formatter).rstrip().encode()
    except:
        return None
 
 
print(colorize_disasm("lea [rip+0x211]  #test", None).decode())
```

[image: Wrong Pygments output for RIP-relative operands]

The (yet to be released) next version uses an entirely different coloring code, where each disassembler function can introduce style markers in its output and the *disassemble* command (see `gdb/disassemble.c`) translates those markers into terminal escapes.